# Deleting a word from a string

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, ksh

I want to delete a specific word from a file.

Let's say the file name `agent_file.txt` contains below string

```
-queues winall,dustat,envstat,netstat,iostat,winconfig,netwarestat,netwareconfig,pawmin,paw15,db2,sqlserver,vmstatvmw2,vmstatvm2,netstatvm,netstatvmw,vmstatvm,vmstatvmw,iostatvm,iostatvmw,envstatvm,envstatvmw,vmscpu,vmsdisk,vmsmem,vmstatvcw,process,winprocess
```

I want to delete character or the word `process` only in this file, so I use below command under Unix

```
perl -pi -e 's/process//g' agent_file.txt
```

The output will be

```
-queues winall,dustat,envstat,netstat,iostat,winconfig,netwarestat,netwareconfig,pawmin,paw15,db2,sqlserver,vmstatvmw2,vmstatvm2,netstatvm,netstatvmw,vmstatvm,vmstatvmw,iostatvm,iostatvmw,envstatvm,envstatvmw,vmscpu,vmsdisk,vmsmem,vmstatvcw,,win
```

The word is deleted, but it also deletes part of `winprocess`.

How can I delete only `process` as well as a preceding comma `,` if there is one?

The output should be

```
-queues winall,dustat,envstat,netstat,iostat,winconfig,netwarestat,netwareconfig,pawmin,paw15,db2,sqlserver,vmstatvmw2,vmstatvm2,netstatvm,netstatvmw,vmstatvm,vmstatvmw,iostatvm,iostatvmw,envstatvm,envstatvmw,vmscpu,vmsdisk,vmsmem,vmstatvcw,winprocess
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's comma separated use them to your advantage for making it a word.

```
perl -pi -e "s/, \s* process\s* , /, /g filename
```

If there is not going to be spaces after or before comma then remove \s*

Answer (score 1):

Use auto-splitting (`-a`) by comma (`-F,`), to avoid the comma-problem altogether

```
perl -F, -lane 'print join ",", grep { not /^process$/ } @F' input  > output
```

Input is broken up by `,` into `@F`. The `grep` filters out the word and the rest is joined back by `,`

In order to change the input file in place add `-i` and drop `> output`

See [Command switches in perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

---

The problem is that the first and last word have one comma, which needs to go if they are removed, while others have two commas where one needs to stay. One way with regex is to make two passes, removing the word and then extra commas (still be careful with first and last).

Or run code in the replacement part to select cases suitably

```
echo "go,stay,ago,go,got,end,go" | 

    perl -pe's/(,)?\bgo\b(,)?/$1 && $2 && ","/ge'
```

Prints: `stay,ago,got,end`.  The [`/e`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) evaluates the replacement side as Perl code.

If both commas are there (`$1 && $2`) then (`&&`) we replace with comma (`","`).

This works because in Perl [`&&` returns the value](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or)

> The `||`, `//` and `&&` operators return the last value evaluated (unlike C's `||` and `&&`, which return 0 or 1).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `awk` solution.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="process") $i=""} 1' file
```

This sets your field separator to comma for both input and output, and then steps through your fields, checking for equivalence against the string you're interested in and emptying the field if it matches.  The `1` at the end is awk short-hand for "print the current line".

---

Similarly, one could slice up input data by record instead of by field:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS=","} /^process$/{next} 1' file
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS=","} $0=="process"{next} 1' file
```

This walks through your input using the comma as a RECORD separator (RS), so that individual words can be evaluated using awk's record-awareness. You can do your evaluation via regex or not -- regex is ever so slightly slower, but appears to save you two characters of typing. :-)

The strategy using RS/ORS eliminates the problem you noticed with the field being emptied but not removed. When the comma is a record separator, then a skipped record causes the record separator not to be shown, which is closer to the "ideal" output you've included in your question.

---

Last option might be to do this right inside your shell (ksh). This will have the advantage of greatest portability (you won't have to worry about perl version, whether awk/sed are GNU or BSD or something else). The disadvantage is that with the method below, your file size will be limited by your system memory (and perhaps configurable limits).

```
$ IFS=, read -A arr < file
$ for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do [[ "${arr[$i]}" == "process" ]] && unset arr[$i]; done
$ output=$(printf "%s," "${arr[@]}")
$ echo "${output%,}"
-queues winall,dustat,envstat,netstat,iostat,winconfig,netwarestat,netwareconfig,pawmin,paw15,db2,sqlserver,vmstatvmw2,vmstatvm2,netstatvm,netstatvmw,vmstatvm,vmstatvmw,iostatvm,iostatvmw,envstatvm,envstatvmw,vmscpu,vmsdisk,vmsmem,vmstatvcw,winprocess
```

Note that the `$output` variable is only required in order to strip the trailing comma generated by `printf`. Another option might be to set `$IFS` more globally:

```
$ IFS=,
$ echo "${arr[*]}"
-queues winall,dustat,envstat,netstat,iostat,winconfig,netwarestat,netwareconfig,pawmin,paw15,db2,sqlserver,vmstatvmw2,vmstatvm2,netstatvm,netstatvmw,vmstatvm,vmstatvmw,iostatvm,iostatvmw,envstatvm,envstatvmw,vmscpu,vmsdisk,vmsmem,vmstatvcw,winprocess
```

I should point out that despite appearances, the `printf` option doesn't really spawn external commands, because ksh implements `printf` as a built-in.

Answer (score 0):

you can do in three steps

```
sed 's/,process,/,/g;s/^process,//;s/,process$//'
```

testing for positions,: in-between, beginning or at the end.

Comment: `\b` appears to be GNU-only. This solution doesn't work in OS X or *BSD.

Comment: Thanks @karakfa this helps a lot,  however this only works in the GNU sed...but not working in my sed which under AIX...=(

Comment: This won't remove the superfluous leading or trailing comma if `process` appears at the start or end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Like this perhaps?

It  searches for all occurrences of `process`, using word boundaries to ensure that it isn't found as part of another word, and also matching optional commas `,` before and after. The match is replaced by a single comma if two commas were found (`process` was found in the middle of the list) and deleted if there was only one (`process` appears only at the beginning or end of the list)

```
perl -pi -e 's/ ,? \b process \b ,? ) / $1 =~ tr/,// > 1 ? ',' : '' /xge' agent_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/process,/,"")}1' file
```